# How to print only a specific page part?

Tags: css

I know that to prevent some page parts from being printed we can add a class and tell CSS that we don't want elements from this class to be printed.
For example:

page.html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class = "section1 donotprint">
  <p>Hey, I'm not printed. Poor me.</p>
</div>
<div class = "section2">
  <p>Hey, I am printed! Lucky me!</p>
</div>
```

print.css:

```
.donotprint {
  display: none;
}
```

And then including `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />` does the magic.

But I'm working on a quite heavy project and I don't want to pollute the code with *donotprint* classes everywhere. So I would like **to specify what I do want to print** instead of specifying what I don't want to. So in my example it would be like that:

page.html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class = "section1">
  <p>Hey, I'm not printed. Poor me.</p>
</div>
<div class = "section2 print">
  <p>Hey, I am printed! Lucky me!</p>
</div>
```

I tried `:not(.print) {display: none;}` but the `display: none;` affects the children as well so nothing is printed (well, the empty `<div class = "section2 print"></div>` is).

So does the CSS allows this kind of thing? And if so, how?

Comment: @media print {.dontprintme {display: none}} // or visibility: hidden / opacity: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `*` selector in combination with immediate child `>`

```
.main > * {       /* Basically the sections */
  display: none; 
}

.main > .print {
  display: initial;
}
```

The above is not flexible like specifically defining *what to hide* - since it'll work for immediate child only.

Answer (score -1):

You can put everything you don't want to print in the print.css file, this is not limited to one class. You can add, for example, something like `nav, header, main, footer {display: none}` to your print.css file to stop these elements from printing.

And then just set display: block to everything you want to print.

You can also change all other attributes, like color/font-size, spacing....

Comment: Tried that but the `* {display: none}` annihilates everything, and then I have to specify every single element to be displayed... I would like to only specify a block to display

Comment: you can also adapt the selector to be more precise, i will update my answer a bit.